# How to pass jquery value to php model function in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

i need to pass jquery ID value in to my est_model->get_img() function in codeigniter and display all the content in the same modal box, i tried my own logic it doesn't work, please help guys, thank you in advance

here is my code below:
modal a tag:

```
<a href="#view_all_img_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-est-id="<?php echo $row->est_id;?>">View all</a>
```

my jquery:

```
$('#view_all_images_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var est_id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('est-id');
    $.ajax({url:"admin/est_view.php?ID="+est_id,cache:false,success:function(result){
        $("#view_all_img_modal").html(result);
    }});

});
```

modal box:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="view_all_img_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="row">
 <?php
  $id=$_GET['ID'];
   $est_img=$this->est_model->get_img($id);
            if($est_img):
    foreach ($est_img as $img):
                $ser_img=($img->img_name==NULL)?'no-image.png':$img->img_name;?>
     <img src="<?php echo base_url('../public/images/rel_img/'.$ser_img);?>">
    <?php endforeach; 
   endif;?>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your PHP file can't read the ID from GET request unless the modal box is in fact `admin/est_view.php` However I think I understand what u'r trying to do,

**STEP 1 :**

create a file called `admin/est_view.php` that contain just the php script that will extract the data from DB and the `foreach clause` to form html response, and don't forget it needs to connect to the database.

Here's an example u can use or develop :

```
<?php
    try{
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=demo", "root", "passwd");
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $e->getMessage());
    }
    try{
        if(isset($_REQUEST["ID"])){
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM images_table WHERE :ID";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $term = $_REQUEST["ID"] . '%';
            $stmt->bindParam(":ID", $term);
            $stmt->execute();
            if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
                while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
                    echo "<img src=\"" . $row["url"] . "\">";
                }
            }
        }  
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        die("ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . $e->getMessage());
    }
    unset($stmt);
    unset($pdo);
?>
```

**STEP 2 :**

Now you can use your own JS :

```
$('#view_all_images_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var est_id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('est-id');
    $.ajax({url:"admin/est_view.php?ID="+est_id,cache:false,success:function(result){
        $("#view_all_img_modal").html(result);
    }});

});
```

Comment: @Kynjai I hope u accept my answer if u find it helpful ;)